# frequency of integers from user input

Tags: java, frequency

This might be simple but I can't figure it out. I'm trying to print out the frequency of the user input. For example how many times the user enters the number 1? Here is some of my code.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Ex2partB {

    public static void main (String ags []) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner ( System.in );

        int number1; 
        int number2;
        int number3;
        int number4;
        int number5;
        int product;

        System.out.print( "Enter first integer: " ); 
        number1 = input.nextInt();

        System.out.print( "Enter second integer: " ); 
        number2 = input.nextInt();

        System.out.print( "Enter third integer: " ); 
        number3 = input.nextInt();

        System.out.print( "Enter fourth integer: " ); 
        number4 = input.nextInt();

        System.out.print( "Enter fifth integer: " ); 
        number5 = input.nextInt();

        product = number1 + number2 + number3 + number4 + number5;

        System.out.printf (" Product is %d\n ", product );

    }
}
```

Comment: Which part are you having trouble with?

Comment: Simply use an array. It is a shame that professors do not teach students pointer early on...

Comment: Product is when you multiply.  Sum is when you add.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following is a very robust approach. It uses a `HashMap`to store the input and its frequency and passes the result to a `TreeMap` to sort the keys and print out the results.

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.TreeMap;

public class App {
    public App() {
        Map<Integer, Integer> map = buildMap();
        printFrequency(map);
    }

    public Map<Integer, Integer> buildMap() {
        Map<Integer, Integer> map = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        int n, key;

        System.out.print("How many numbers will you enter?: ");
        n = input.nextInt();

        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            System.out.printf("Enter integer #%d: ", i + 1);
            key = input.nextInt();
            map.put(key, map.containsKey(key) ? map.get(key) + 1 : 1);
        }

        input.close();

        return map;
    }

    public void printFrequency(Map<Integer, Integer> map) {
        Map<Integer, Integer> treeMap = new TreeMap<Integer, Integer>(map);

        System.out.println("\nValue\tFrequency");

        for (Integer key : treeMap.keySet()) {
            System.out.printf("%5d\t%9d\n", key, treeMap.get(key));
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new App();
    }
}
```

Example run:

```
How many numbers will you enter?: 10
Enter integer #1: 1
Enter integer #2: 2
Enter integer #3: 3
Enter integer #4: 2
Enter integer #5: 3
Enter integer #6: 4
Enter integer #7: 1
Enter integer #8: 2
Enter integer #9: 2
Enter integer #10: 5

Value   Frequency
    1           2
    2           4
    3           2
    4           1
    5           1
```

Comment: I tested it. Thats actually very good. It definitely presents the answer in the best format. Thanks so much for this should be very useful in future assignments.

Answer (score 0):

Store the input in a hash map. If the input is already in the hash map then increment the value for that key. You will then have the frequency of input as the value in the map.

Comment: "For example how many times the user enters the number 1?" Is this an example, or will the input definitely be integer input? If the input is integer input, an array based solution like the one peeskillet is suggesting is more efficient.

Comment: Ya an integer input. Thanks for the help aswell.

Answer (score 0):

You need to put a `max` constraint on how large the input number can be. Let's say the "pick a number beteen 1 and 10". So you can make an array of size 10;

```
int[] array = new int[10];
```

Initialize the values with 0;

```
for (int i = 0; i > 10; i++){
    array[i] = 0;
}
```

Now every time you get an input number, just increase the index. But remember, the indices are zero based, so for 10, you want to use the index 9

For example, lets say user input is 10. Then youd increse the 9th index like this

```
array[number1 - 1]++;  //
```

And do this for the remaining inputs.

To print the values just loop through the array

```
for (int i = 0; i < array.length) {
    System.out.println((i + 1) + " : " + array[i]);
}
```

Comment: I believe integers, including arrays of integers, are initialized to zero, so the initialization loop is not necessary.